# restored a deleted file in github but can't push it back up

Tags: git, github

I'm learning github and experimenting with restoring deleted files so I deleted a text file `git rm game.txt` then committed and pushed then I restored the file in my local repo `git reset --hard "checksum of last commit/push"` which restored the file.

i then edited the file so git would recognize the modification and allow the commit, but when I try to commit i get this error: `CONFLICT (modify/delete): game.txt deleted in 45698cbb2b278bf213adf4aef39548bf74fff0ed and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of game.txt left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.`

so what i want to know is: 1) how can i resolve this conflict. 2) is this best way to restore deleted files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local and github now are separate branches, both originating from the commit you reset to.  You have to merge from github into your local branch; when you do this merge you will have to solve the conflict between the deleted version and the modified version.  After you have merged locally, you will be able to push the merged version back to github.

There are a variety of ways to restore deleted files in git; I don't think this way is the best way.  If you have already published a commit that deletes a file, your best bet might be to use `git revert` to create a new commit that undoes the commit that removed the file.